# App is not working on WAMP but It works in online server

Tags: php, android, sqlite

I made a basic login app using online SQLite database(http://demo3534535.16mb.com)
It works fine on online server.
Now i want to run on local server using WAMP in Gennymotion emulator.

What change in code i have to do?
    My working online code is:

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
    define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
    define('USER','u756_userd');
    define('PASS','pass345');
    define('DB','u754113_demo');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


  private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.102/User/Register.php";

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";


    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    private Button buttonRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonRegister){
            registerUser();
        }
    }
}
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','db_demo');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

Register.php

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO volley (username,password,email) VALUES ('$username','$email','$password')";


        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo "Successfully Registered";
        }else{
            echo "Could not register";

        }
    }else{
echo 'error';
}
```

I am using internet via wifi

Comment: hard to say what the problem is. did you open port 80 on your router to redirect  (HTTP Requests) to the local server's IP thats using WAMP??

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: What does the server return ? 'error' or 'Could not register' ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're going local, follow these steps:

1. You need to create a WLAN. Open the command prompt Admin mode and type these commands:

   ```
   netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=DevelopmentLAN key=yourPassword
   ```

   Press OK. Then execute the following command:

   ```
   netsh wlan start hostednetwork
   ```

This shall **start your WLAN**.

Now type `ipconfig` in the command line, so that you discover your machine's IPv4 address:

[image: ipconfig]

**EDIT:**

Make sure you are noting your **Wireless LAN adapter**'s IPv4 address.

Note this IP address. This is the one you are going to use as the ***HOST*** address.

***The Configuration part.***

Change    `define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');`

**to this** `define('HOST','localhost');`

As for the rest, you need to change the user's name, password and the database name to your **WAMPServer**'s username and password and your database 's name on WAMP, respectively.

Now I will suppose that your **register.php** file is wrapped inside a **User** folder in your WAMP projects directory (C:/wamp/www/User/register.php). Change `REGISTER_URL`'s value to this:

```
private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.3/User/register.php";
```

And that's it, you're ready to go. Finally make sure your **firewall is OFF**, otherwise **it will block** your genymotion emulator from **connecting** to the WAMP server on your machine, and that you change **192.168.1.3** to your machine's IP address.

Comment: Please elaborate. Show your error logs, and anything that could help us so that we could help you.

Comment: Thanks for answring but i am sorry to say that i am still not able to run my app on gennymotion. I have no username and password for wamp then what i have to put there?,  left it blank or put 'root' for both username and password. i turned off my pc firewell also. is it secure to turnoff  firewall?

Comment: Put 'root' for the username and leave the password empty. Turning off the firewall is required for this to work, I don't know any trick how to by pass it otherwise.

Comment: i modified my question with more details. please check it out

Comment: I checked it but it does not shown because my reputation is below 15 i am new to this site.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help. Me too I ran across the same problem as you did a month ago and I had to find out the solution myself because I couldn't find the solution elsewhere.

Comment: Great!! you are really a genius. I was also searching the solution for this but i failed to find it. Finally i got solution after a week. Thanks to you.

Comment: I'm really glad that I could help ! Good luck pal :)