# Populate recyclerview with cardview using php and mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml

I have a recyclerView with a cardview on it. I would like to populate the recyclerview and supply data to cardview from my MySQL database. My homepagelayout contains the recyclerview. While `cardview.xml` has the cardview layout. I've used `ArrayList` to populate my cardview. Is there any way to get data from database and then insert it into my `ArrayList`? I think JSON will do but I don't know how to create a JSON and parse it to my java code.

In my hompage.java, I temporarily create a `ArrayList`. I wanted to change it and retrieve my data from my database.

**Homepage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment {
    private LinearLayoutManager lLayout;

    public HomePage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepagelayout, container, false);


        lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        List<Cities_list> rowListItem = getAllItemList();

        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
        RecycleViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    private List<Cities_list> getAllItemList(){

        List<Cities_list> allItems = new ArrayList<Cities_list>();
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("Pasig City", R.drawable.pic14));
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("Marikina City", R.drawable.pic13));
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("Antipolo City", R.drawable.pic10));
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("Quezon City", R.drawable.pic11));
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("Muntinlupa City", R.drawable.pic12));
        allItems.add(new Cities_list("BLabla City", R.drawable.pic13));
        return allItems;
    }
}
```

**RecycleViewAdapter.java**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<Cities_list> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<Cities_list> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewHolders.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView countryName;
    public ImageView countryPhoto;
    public Context context;
    Intent intent;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Context context=view.getContext();
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, City.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you successfully established a connection between your app and the MySQL database through PHP ?

Comment: Honestly, ive only tried it in my registration page but i havent tried it in my homepage. Im a little confused on where to place it. By the way, Im using API 23 so I must use URLConnection.

Comment: Check this question, on how to setup WAMPServer for use with Android : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462560/app-is-not-working-on-wamp-but-it-works-in-online-server/33462732#33462732

Comment: Thanks for this :) Sir , how i can i retrieve data from my database then populate my cardview ?

Comment: Honestly, I need like 30 minutes to explain write down an answer on how to do it, but I think that link covers the basics. Check the OP's code, try to understand his code (client and server side)

Comment: Thanks sir. Do i need to use a JSON to get data from database then set it to my cardview ?

Comment: You will be sending POST requests to your PHP server. From the client side(your Android app), you will only specify the POST request parameters & their values. You access those $_POST parameters on the server side & you perform the required operations (connect to database, check user login, logout, sessions etc...) & then you send the result back to your Android app (`echo $result`). You will need an `AsyncTask` to send the request & to receive the results from the server. It's likely that you will need to parse JSON results (if you use `json_encode` on server side). It's a long process.

Comment: Thanks Sir :) it would be a big big help :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome & I'm sorry, I would have given you a complete answer but it's not as short as it may look like. Good luck !